# How to get a list of all hardware specs on a Windows 10 PC that is reset?

Tags: windows-10, bios, specifications

Is there a way to quickly check all of the hardware specs on a PC that has been reset? I am planning to buy a laptop on Craigslist and want to be sure that I'm not getting ripped off or misled. The current owner has reset the laptop, which makes sense, but I don't want to just take his word that it's the same specs as advertised online.

Bottom line is I won't buy it without checking, but I would prefer to do it quickly rather than going through Windows setup in a parking lot somewhere. I would need to see the CPU, GPU, RAM, and storage, and I'm skeptical that all of that info will be on the BIOS (pretty sure that I can't see GPU on my BIOS, for instance).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of that information definitely should be in the BIOS.  However, as an alternative you can create a Linux Mint Live 19 USB or DVD to boot from.  Once booted, type `system info` into the search box to find the System Info app.  Select it and it will give you CPU, memory, hard drive, and GPU information.

Other Linux distro's Live environments probably will have the same app, or something similar.  However, I just happen to have a Mint 19 Live USB and a laptop in front of me, so I can verify that the System Info app is in the Live environment.